# Where am I getting lost in basis change.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

For a linear transformation F we're given that F(0,1,0)=(1,1,0), F(0,0,1)=(1,-1,2), and that (1,1,1) is an eigenvector with eigenvalue=1. Find the transformation matrix for F.

I know this can be solved by just using linearity: (1,0,0) = (1,1,1)-(0,1,0)-(0,0,1) so using linearity of the transformation, F((1,0,0)) = F((1,1,1)-(0,1,0)-(0,0,1)) gives the image of the "missing" basis vector and thus the matrix (call it $A$), which is: $A$= \begin{pmatrix}-1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1\\ -1&0&2\end{pmatrix}

However, this also seemed straightforward to solve by changing to a new basis given by: e_1= (0, 1, 0), e_2 = (0, 0, 1) and e_3 = (1, 1, 1). I'm thinking that in the new basis, the transformation matrix ($\hat{A}$) must be the following, given the information about the images of the vectors under the transformation given: $\hat{A}$=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\ 1&-1&1\\ 0&2&1\end{pmatrix}

If we call the coordinate transformation matrix  S=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
Then we should have: $\hat{A} = S^{-1}AS$, and therefore $A = S\hat{A}S^{-1}$ should result in the same matrix as the first one above, but instead I get back:
\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&2\\ -2&1&3\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
So I'm obviously getting lost somewhere but I cannot figure out where. If anyone could point out my mistake(s) I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Hello, +1 for all the details. I don't understand the matrix $\hat{A}$ that you obtain. You should have for example $F(e_1) = -e_2 + e_3$ so the first column should be $(0 ~ -1 ~~ 1)^T$ (transposition of this line).

Comment: My thinking is that the columns of the transformation matrix will be the image of the basis vectors after the transformation. So since we've switched to a basis where e_1=(0,1,0) and we're given that F(0,1,0) = (1,1,0), the first column of $\hat{A}$ should be (1,1,0) and so on for the two other columns.

Comment: I see, this is not the right way to think. If you have a linear transformation $F : (E,B) \to (E,B)$ with $E$ a vector space with basis $B$, the transformation matrix of $F$ with respect to the basis $B$ is given by this rule : if $B = (e_1, \dotsc, e_n)$ and $F(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}e_j$, the $j$-th column should be $(a_{1,j} ~ a_{2,j} ~ \dotsc ~ a_{n-1,j} ~ a_{n,j})^T$.

Comment: I see. I guess the rule that the columns are the images of the basis vectors only happens to be true in the standard basis then. Either way, that must be the source of the error, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: In fact, the matrix $\hat{A}$ of your initial post is the matrix of the linear transformation $F : (\mathbb R^3, B) \to (\mathbb R^3, C)$ with $B = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$ (the vectors that you have defined) and $C$ the canonical basis. If I have the time to do it, I'll write a complete answer.